# Proguard on ShareSDK. Got an Exception NoClassDefFoundError: com.mob.tools.utils.R

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am using Proguard to obfuscate my Android Application. My application is using ShareSDK library.

While i use share function. I got NoClassDefFoundError as title.

I have add proguard-rules in my proguard-rules.pro as below:

```
-keep class cn.sharesdk.**{*;}
-keep class com.sina.**{*;}
-keep class **.R$* {*;}
-keep class **.R{*;}
-dontwarn cn.sharesdk.**
-dontwarn **.R$*
-keep class m.framework.**{*;}
-keep class com.mob.**{*;}
-dontwarn com.mob.**
```

And I have checked mapping.txt that having sentences below:

```
com.mob.tools.utils.R -> com.mob.tools.utils.R:
float density -> density
int deviceWidth -> deviceWidth
java.lang.Object rp -> rp
void <init>() -> <init>
...
```

so i think the class `com.mob.tools.utils.R` was kept.

Can anyone tell me how can i do to find this class?

Answer (score 0):

**Add this into your proguard.pro file**

```
    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
  public static **[] values();
  public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
 }
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
-adaptresourcefilenames    **.properties,**.gif,**.jpg,**.png,**.xml
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,**.xml
-dontwarn android.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn android.support.design.*
-dontwarn org.objenesis.**
```

**Update**

add following also to your proguard file.

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-ignorewarnings
-repackageclasses ''
    -allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keepattributes *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes Signature


-keepclassmembers public class cn.sharesdk.**{
<init>(...);
*;
}

-keepclassmembers public class com.sina.**{
    <init>(...);
    *;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but i still get the same error. I saw there is `com.mob.tools.utils.R -> com.mob.tools.utils.R:` in mapping.txt, that means the class was kept, doesn't it?